# Laravel tracker page with multiple authintication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have some difficulty to setup `antonioribeiro/tracker` with multiple authentication. I just want to admin guard only have access to this page. I set up the `tracker.php` as follow:

```
'stats_routes_middleware' => 'auth:admins',

/*
 * Laravel internal variables on user authentication and login.
 */
'authentication_ioc_binding' => ['auth'], // defaults to 'auth' in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
'authenticated_check_method' => 'check', // to Auth::check()
'authenticated_user_method' => 'user', // to Auth::user()
'authenticated_user_id_column' => 'id', // to Auth::user()->id
'authenticated_user_username_column' => 'username', // to Auth::user()->email
```

currently when I try to access `Mywebsite/stats` it will redirect to admin login even after I log in with admin trying to reach the stats page I get redirected to admin login.

if I change the `stats_routes_middleware` to `'web'` it works just fine but when I change to admin middle ware I can not reach the stats page.

I'm using laravel 5.4

Comment: So, you're not an admin. What have you done to debug the authentication middleware?

Comment: I couldn't really debug the authentication middleware. Could you you give me a clue how to debug further? I tied to debug through Exception handle didn't work out though...

Comment: You can edit it, as any other php file, and add as much logging as required. It's in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php`. It may also be relevant to debug your "admins" guard, but that isn't part of default Laravel so I cannot tell you where that is. Start looking in your `config/auth.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the clue sisve. The guard is set correctly  for admin, however the user is treated as gust. That's why it requires authentication. I have no clue though why it ask me to authenticate again after I login..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to resolve the issue:

tracker.php:

'authentication_ioc_binding' => ['App\Admin'],// defaults to 'auth' in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

```
'authenticated_check_method' => 'check', // to Auth::check()

'authenticated_user_method' => 'user', // to Auth::user()

'authenticated_user_id_column' => 'id', // to Auth::user()->id

'authenticated_user_username_column' => 'username', 
'stats_routes_middleware' => 'web',
```

My admin model:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
protected $guard = "admins";


public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return true;
}

public static function check()
{
    return Auth::guard('admins')->check();
}

public static function user()
{
    return Auth::guard('admins')->user();
}
```